# TypoScript to add a class only for "li" elements belonging to an "ol" list

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

the next TS code works great for my TYPO3 7.6 installation:

```
tt_content.highlight_list.20.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks = table,blockquote,ol,li,ul
tt_content.highlight_list.20.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks {
    ul {
        stripNL = 1
        callRecursive = 1
        callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.ul.fixAttrib.class.default = row
    }
    li {
        stripNL = 1
        callRecursive = 1
        callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
        callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.li.fixAttrib.class.default = col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2
    }
    ol {
        stripNL = 1
        callRecursive = 1
        callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
    }
}
```

Now I would like the class **col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2** is not present for **li** items only belonging to **ol** elements. For **ul**, they should be kept.

Trying the next line (or other variants) just breaks the markup:

```
tt_content.highlight_list.20.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks.ol.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.li.fixAttrib.class.default =
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible, since the tags are handled equal in
`tt_content.highlight_list.20.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks = table,blockquote,ol,li,ul`

To get similar results,
target `ol>li` and `ul>li` directly via css,
*or*
unset `ol>li.col-4.col-sm-2.col-md-2` styles.

Should be quicker to do than to hassle with typoscript, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is that for TYPO3 6.1.12, the next Typoscript added the classes "col-4.col-sm-2.col-md-2" only to "ol" lists:

```
tt_content.highlight_list.20.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks = table,blockquote,ol,ul,li
tt_content.highlight_list.20.text.20.parseFunc.externalBlocks {
  li.stripNL = 1
  li.callRecursive = 1
  li.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
  li.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.li {
    fixAttrib.class.default = col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2
  }
  ul.stripNL = 1
  ul.callRecursive = 1
  ul.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
  ul.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.ul {
    fixAttrib.class.default = row
  }
}
```